# How do I position a texture on a 3D Object?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I have a 3D object, e.g a cube, in WPF that consists of one **MeshGeometry3D** and one **GeometryModel3D**.
Now I want to apply a **Material** to the object at a specific position.

For example, I have a **DiffuseMaterial** with a **SolidColorBrush**. When I apply it to my object, the whole object is painted with the given color.

What I want is to color only one side of the cube. I have seen that I can apply a viewport, rectangles and everything else to a material. 
So how can I define a material, that only paints a specific part of the object?

I have seen examples where the objects is splitted into many geometries, which I want to avoid, if possible. I just want to define everything in the material itself. Is that possible?

Edit: What I want to achieve is a cylinder with a number on top of it. That's all. :)
The cylinder is one single Geometrymodel. I'm a total newby to wpf 3d and I thought it would be much easier to just create a material with a textblock or something, that I can put on the whole cylinder.

Comment: Sure, there are ways. They're practically guaranteed to perform worse then separating the mesh, though. You could use a texture (and map the UV coordinates appropriately) where all the sides are one color except for one, you could use a transparent texture, which would only have opaque colour where you don't want the cube color, you could write your own shader code... The question is - why? What are you trying to accomplish? Are you drawing a logo, a simple scene, a Minecraft-y world? That makes all the difference :)

Comment: Ok, I have now separated the meshes from each other.
Now I have a simple "circle" in 3D - a disc like object. On this object, I want to put a texture, but I don't get how to calculate the texture coordinates. I have the positions and the triangles, but I don't really know how to define the texture coordinates...